# Recover Account functionality For WCF rest API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, jwt, password-recovery

I am looking for the working example of "Recover Account or Forgot Password" For WCF RestAPis.

What I have tried?

I have build a Forget Password API, which takes email as an input parameter and if email exists in the database, it genertes an "JWT Identity Token" contains encypted **userID** and **expiration** Date as a payload and sent it to email as a link.

token is generted as per this example: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1208535/Create-and-Consume-JWT-Tokens-in-Csharp

That link will hit another API which takes the token and encrypt it, if the expiration time does not get passed, then it will allow updation of the password against the **userID**

Now my concerns over the above approach are:

- Is it even right way to do it?
- when password gets changed, how to make token to gets expired?
- What are the other ways?

Thanks In advance